# Can/should a child actor use a property of its parent?

Tags: akka, akka.net

In a situation like this:

```
Data Data;
public ParentActor(Data data)
{
     Data  = data;
     Context.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new ChildActor()))
}
```

In the child actor is it a good practice to use:
`(Context.Parent as ParentActor).Data; } }`
or is this against the akka principle?

Or is passing `Data` in de ctor of `ChildActor` the correct way to go?

Does it perhaps depend upon whether `Data` is mutable/immutable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just that it's not a good practice, it CANNOT be done. Context.Parent gives you an ActorRef which is in no way castable to ParentActor. An ActorRef is merely a reference to send messages to an actor, nothing else, it has no relationship with the class of the actor.

In any case, by akka's principles, you should never share mutable state between actors; your actor's mutable state should never leak out of your actors. If you need to send a part of your state to another actor, make sure it is immutable, or else make an immutable copy before sending it on a message. As you mentioned, you could pass Data on the constructor if your child actor is going to be using it often, but it has to be immutable, otherwise, again, pass an immutable copy.

The rationale behind this is that any two actors can be running simultaneously at a given point in time. If two actors share access to a mutable object, they may concurrently modify it, resulting in race conditions and non-deterministic behavior from either actor's perspective. Of course, you could use thread-safe data structures, but that would be defeating the whole purpose of akka, which is to allow you to think of message processing as if you were running on a single thread.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I did some more research and found the correct way to proceed  in https://github.com/petabridge/akkadotnet-code-samples/tree/master/PipeTo. Because actually I wanted to achieve parallel processing. I now see that 1 actor with the state can handle all messages parallel (or async/task) using PipeTo which sends the result to its own inbox. That is a nice concept!

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to akka.net myself, but my understanding of the actor model suggests that you should always try to pass data via messages wherever possible, rather than via method calls or constructor arguments.